# SQL Server : Sum over a field changed after adding a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have a sample query like this:

```
;WITH view1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS pId, 'a' AS pName, 1 AS kind 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'a', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'a', 1 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'b', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2, 'b', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'b', 1 
), view2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS pId, 'a' AS pName, 5 AS price
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, 'c', 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'b', 3 
)   
SELECT 
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId) AS pId,
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName) AS pName,
    SUM(CASE v1.kind WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countKind1,
    SUM(v2.price) AS sumPrice
FROM 
    view1 v1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    view2 v2 ON v1.id = v2.id
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId),
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName)
```

Its result is:

```
pId | pName | countKind1 | sumPrice
----+-------+------------+-----------
1   | a     | 1          | 5
2   | b     | 1          | 3 
3   | c     | 1          | 3
```

But I wanted this result after adding `ISNULL`s and `sumPrice`:

```
pId | pName | countKind1 | sumPrice
----+-------+------------+-----------
1   | a     | 2          | 5
2   | b     | 1          | 3 
3   | c     | 0          | 3
```

Comment: are you sure you want to join on id and not `pId`?

Comment: This data and query is just a view of my big query that is in this way; and with finding a simple way to achieve this I will be able to handle that big query ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for with using a inline select:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId) AS pId,
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName) AS pName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view1 vi WHERE vi.kind = 1 AND vi.pId = ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId)) AS countKind1,
    SUM(v2.price) AS sumPrice
FROM 
    view1 v1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    view2 v2 ON v1.id = v2.id
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId),
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName)
```

---

And this one:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId) AS pId,
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName) AS pName,
    ISNULL(tc.Counts, 0) AS countKind1,
    SUM(v2.price) AS sumPrice
FROM 
    view1 v1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    view2 v2 ON v1.id = v2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT vi.pId, COUNT(*) Counts FROM view1 vi WHERE vi.kind = 1 GROUP BY vi.pId) AS tc ON tc.pId = ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId)
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId),
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName),
    tc.Counts
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks a bit weird. I can create a few ways of getting desired result, but I'm not sure what's the meaning behind your data. In general, I'd always advice group your data as early as you can, so you probably could group `view1` and then join by `pId`.

Here's the query which gives your results, though

```
;WITH view1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS pId, 'a' AS pName, 1 AS kind 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'a', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'a', 1 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'b', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2, 'b', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'b', 1 
), view2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS pId, 'a' AS pName, 5 AS price
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, 'c', 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'b', 3 
), cte1 as (
SELECT 
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId) AS pId,
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName) AS pName,
    SUM(v2.price) AS sumPrice
FROM 
    view1 v1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    view2 v2 ON v1.id = v2.id
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId),
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName)
), cte2 as (
    select pName, sum(case when kind = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as countKind1
    from view1
    group by pName
)
select
    c1.pId,
    c1.pName,
    isnull(c2.countKind1, 0) as countKind1,
    c1.sumPrice
from cte1 as c1
    left outer join cte2 as c2 on c2.pName = c1.pName
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/42)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks and (+1), But I  will wait for a simpler query ;).

Answer (score 1):

As per @Roman's comment, you'll want to join on pID.
You'll also need to change the `JOIN` to a `FULL OUTER` join since `view1` has no 'c's
Finally, `SUM(Price)` looks wrong - if this is price per 'each', you'll want to use a different aggregate, like `Max`:

```
;WITH view1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS pId, 'a' AS pName, 1 AS kind 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'a', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'a', 1 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'b', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2, 'b', 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'b', 1 
), view2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS pId, 'a' AS pName, 5 AS price
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, 'c', 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'b', 3 
)   
SELECT 
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId) AS pId,
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName) AS pName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v1.kind = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countKind1,
    MAX(v2.price) AS maxPrice
FROM 
    view1 v1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    view2 v2 ON v1.pid = v2.pid
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(v2.pId, v1.pId),
    ISNULL(v2.pName, v1.pName)
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/43)

Comment: Another option on Price would be to simply add it to the `GROUP BY` and drop the aggregate on it altogether, [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/47)

Comment: Thanks, But I really want to join over `Id`.